# Should there be individual tags for specific plants?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be individual tags for specific plants?

For example, I asked a question specifically about my Gardenia tree/bush/plant.

I'd love to see other questions and answers about Gardenias. Does it make sense to have a tag for Gardenias?

Comment: This is how we have been categorizing plants and trees on this site. See for instance, [tag:dahlias], [tag:sunflowers], [tag:roses], [tag:cherries], [tag:apples], etc. You might not have enough rep to create a tag yet... I believe it requires 150 rep. Luckily, the [tag:gardenias] tag already exists :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes it does!

The only catch I have is that tags with fewer than 2 questions will age away so we will have to readd rare plants. But yes, tags for plants is definitely a good idea.